# How do I match the height of the table to the width of the table when the width is in a percent?

Tags: html, html-table, width, matching

I am creating a table in html where I have defined the widths to be a certain % of the page, but would like to make the resulting spaces form a square.  So if I have put the width to 25% as below:

```
<td width="25%" height="XX"></td>
```

How do I get the height to match the width?

For example, if the browser is open to a 1000 pixel width, the column will be 250 pixels, and I want the height to also be 250 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "pure" HTML/CSS you can't.

The only thing you can do is use Javascript, get the table's width, and set the height to the same level.

A simple method would be:

```
var e = document.getElementById('MYID');
e.height = e.style.width + 'px';
```

This may not be entirely reliable across all browsers though ... Jquery provides `height()`, `outerHeight()` and a bunch of other functions which may be more reliable across different browsers ...